# How to plot two datasets from two different columns from one file in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have one file with two columns containing A/D-samples from two sources. All values are within the range 0-1023 (inclusive) and the sources are not dependant on each other. That is, they are completely different.

Sample excerpt from the datafile:

```
188   631
196   593
203   594
210   593
218   595
225   593
233   594
240   602
247   593
255   594
262   593
269   594
277   593
284   594
```

All the values in the first column belongs to A/D-source #1, while all the values in the second column belongs to A/D-source #2.

Now, what I what to do is to get two lines/plots of the respective A/D-source, in the same plot. Since this is my first shot at Gnuplot, I have a hard time to get it right since it seems that no matter what I do Gnuplot interprets the datafile lines as (X, Y) rather than (Y1, Y2) which is what I want. Doing a plain `plot 'datafile'` will simply bomb all values in a scattered mess.

How do I tell Gnuplot that this particular file contains two datasets, one in each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot 'datafile' using 0:1, 'datafile' using 0:2
```

Column 0 is a 'pseudocolumn' that evaluates to the ordinal number of the current data point (usually the line number). If only a single column of data is present the program assumes that x = column(0) and y = column(1).  The command given above gives the full specification of what to do with the columns, but a simpler form is also accepted:

```
plot 'datafile' using 1, '' using 2
```